# Android Emulator: Receive SMS sent from emulator on a port

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I intend to use the Android Emulator to send/receive SMS.

I send SMS to the emulator using the `sms send` command. I'm aware of emulators being able to converse with each other over SMS but would it possible to receive that the SMS reply sent  from an Android Emulator on a external TCP port?

Any pointers would be very appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can start 2nd Android Virtual Device, one for send SMS another for retrieve SMS.

In the receiver field, you have to input the port number of another AVD, it's in the left up corner od the AVD window (ex. 5554:myAVD, actually it's port number).Of course you have to create 2 AVDs.

And you can use ddms to monitor the logcat message between these two AVDs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply XC. However, I do not want to send messages between two AVDs; I want to relay the message sent from an AVD (Emulator) to an external entity (TCP port).