# How to: get the port number of AVD and send a message to itself

Tags: android

How can I do the following?

1. get the port number of my AVD [from my code not command line .]
2. send a message from AVD to itself using the port number obtained in step 1.

(It's possible: *[could one emulator send a SMS to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676866/could-one-emulator-send-a-sms-to-itself)*)

Answer (score 1):

Sending an SMS from console:

1) Open a console;

2) Type 'telnet localhost xxxx' where xxxx is the emulator ID.  This is the same number that precedes your emulator's name in its title bar, usually 5554 unless you have additional emulators running;

3) Type 'sms send 1234567 message' where message is the text of the SMS message

4) Watch the notification bar on your emulator, and you'll see an SMS message delivered

As long as you're willing to be a meatware SMS gateway, manually transmitting messages between emulators, you can get what you want.

**Sending SMS between emulator instances:**

Use the emulator ID as the phone number.  It seems that the emulators use dummy phone numbers in the format 1 555 521 xxxx where xxxx is the emulator id, e.g. 1 555 521 5554.

Comment: i wanna test wether my app can send sms . so doing it from console won't work .. :)

Comment: Edited answer.  Try it, works for me.  If your SMS functionality works, then you should be able to duplicate my result.

Comment: Emulator thing didn't work but tested on real device and worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Very nice question: My answer is also a bit complicated, but easy:
Yes...You can obtain the port number on which AVD is running.
**Simple. You have to:**

1. obtain the phone number of the emulator
2. The last four digits of the phone number is the port number 5554, 5556, etc.

**Code Snippet:**

```
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
        String portNumber = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length() - 4, phoneNumber.length());
        Log.d(TAG, "Line1 number # " + portNumber);
        tv1.setText(portNumber);
```

**In Manifest File allow permission:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: If anyone Using Emu. M API 23 then permission problem is there.. so you have to add run time permission