# 1555521 is added as a prefix to short numbers

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using Android Studio 2.3 and the Visual Studio x86 emulator. Lately, when I dialed a short number, eg 1234, the number displayed in the dialing screen said 1234. However, the call log said the number dialed was `1 555-521-1234`.

It so happened that there was automatically upgrade and migration to Android Studio 3 today. After the upgrade, the same weird phenomena still happens.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The short number you're using is the port for a different emulator, right?

Comment: No.  I was actually dialing the 4-digit number of the local customer service hotline.  But the same phenomena happened to 1234 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With different emulators, you can send messages or even make calls between different ones by writing the port of an emulator as the phone number. So if oyu have two emulators running at :5554 and :5556, you can send messages to one of them by using the port number.

A while ago, not related to the AS 3.0 update, htese numbers started appearing as `1 555-521-[xxxx]`. 555 is the area code you often see in american movies, it's essentially used for the fake phone numbers. the `1` in front is the country prefix for America. `+1 [phone number]` means an american number.

Google is based in America, and as such a lot of things is American. Like phone numbers. If you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16382341/6296561) you see that it explains adding `1 555-521` before the port. The emulators on this is written to be close to the real thing, so they also emulate the phone numbers by adding the [555 prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number)) and adding the American country code and 521 (random number from the looks of things) and the port number last.

It isn't a bug that this is showing up. It's actually by design that it shows an entire phone number when you try to use emulators.

Essentially, `1 555-521-5554` in the emulator is the same as `5554` when sending messages or making calls. Even though it appears like this it has the same functionality and works just like normal.

Comment: Is there an option to disable this? The local telco I am working with has a 4-digit CS hotline number. I am doing something for them specifically on their hotline. I feel more comfortable being able to test everything is working before pushing to Play Store.

Comment: If you really want to test this, use a real device. There is no way to disable it as far as I know, but this issue only exists with emulators. Real devices don't do this